# Resizing swt-table without forcing their scrollbars

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

following code gives me a construct like in the picture-link below. For instance I have one main group with 3 groups inside. Every group has a table with 3 columns and a minimum width of 200. If you resize the composite, the tables and groups resizes as well. But if the size is smaller than 200, there appears a scrollbar under every single table. In fact my intention was to see ONE scrollbar under the tables. I've tried also a ScrolledComposite-"Layer" between maingroup and the smaller groups, but it didnt work.
Can someone give me an example how can i create one scrollbar instead of 3?

Thanks!

picture: http://www.bilder-upload.eu/show.php?file=d94e50-1432047327.jpg

```
public class GroupTable
{
    private static Composite composite;
    private static ArrayList<Table> tablesList = new ArrayList<Table>();
    private static int              minWidth   = 100;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

        composite = new Composite(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(1, false);
        layout.marginWidth = layout.marginHeight = layout.horizontalSpacing = 0;
        composite.setLayout(layout);

        // MainGroup
        Group gr = new Group(composite, SWT.NONE);
        GridLayout gLayout = new GridLayout(3, false);
        gr.setLayout(gLayout);
        GridData griddata = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false);
        gr.setLayoutData(griddata);
        gr.setText("Main Group");

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            createGroups(gr, layout, i);
        }

        composite.addControlListener(new ControlAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void controlResized(ControlEvent e)
            {
                for (Table table : tablesList)
                {
                    Point size = table.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT);
                    ScrollBar vBar = table.getVerticalBar();
                    Composite group = table.getParent();
                    Rectangle area = group.getClientArea();
                    Rectangle t1 = area;
                    Rectangle t2 = table.computeTrim(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    Point t3 = vBar.getSize();

                    int width = t1.width - t2.width - t3.x;
                    if (size.y > area.height + table.getHeaderHeight())
                    {
                        // Subtract the scrollbar width from the total column
                        // width if a vertical scrollbar will be required
                        Point vBarSize = vBar.getSize();
                        width -= vBarSize.x;
                    }

                    TableColumn[] columnse = table.getColumns();
                    int colCount = columnse.length;
                    Point oldSize = table.getSize();
                    if (oldSize.x > area.width)
                    {
                        // table is getting smaller so make the columns
                        // smaller first and then resize the table to
                        // match the client area width
                        for (TableColumn column : columnse)
                        {
                            if (width / colCount < minWidth)
                            {
                                width = minWidth * colCount;
                            }
                            column.setWidth(width / 3);
                        }
                        table.setSize(area.width, area.height);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // table is getting bigger so make the table
                        // bigger first and then make the columns wider
                        // to match the client area width
                        table.setSize(area.width, area.height);
                        for (TableColumn column : columnse)
                        {
                            if (width / colCount < minWidth)
                            {
                                width = minWidth * colCount;
                            }
                            column.setWidth(width / 3);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        shell.setSize(900, 400);
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed())
        {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

    private static void createGroups(Composite parentGroup, GridLayout layout, int i)
    {
        Group group = new Group(parentGroup, SWT.NONE);
        group.setLayout(layout);
        GridData griddata1 = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
        group.setLayoutData(griddata1);
        group.setText("group " + i);
        createTables(group, i);
    }

    private static void createTables(Group parent, int tn)
    {
        Table table = new Table(parent, SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
        tablesList.add(table);
        TableViewer localTableViewer = new TableViewer(table);
        localTableViewer.getControl().setLayoutData(
                new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            TableViewerColumn column = new TableViewerColumn(localTableViewer,
                    SWT.NONE);
            column.getColumn().setText("column " + j);
            column.getColumn().pack();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
            item.setText(new String[]{"i ", "am", "table " + tn});
        }
        table.setHeaderVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using a `ScrolledComposite`:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    ScrolledComposite scrolledComposite = new ScrolledComposite(shell, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
    scrolledComposite.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    Composite content = new Composite(scrolledComposite, SWT.NONE);
    content.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, true));

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        Table table = new Table(content, SWT.BORDER);
        table.setHeaderVisible(true);
        table.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

        for(int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
        {
            TableColumn column = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
            column.setText("Col " + col);
        }

        for(int row = 0; row < 10; row++)
        {
            TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);

            for(int col = 0; col < table.getColumnCount(); col++)
            {
                item.setText(col, "Item " + row + " " + col);
            }
        }

        for(int col = 0; col < table.getColumnCount(); col++)
        {
            table.getColumn(col).pack();
        }


    }

    scrolledComposite.setContent(content);
    scrolledComposite.setExpandHorizontal(true);
    scrolledComposite.setExpandVertical(true);
    scrolledComposite.setMinSize(content.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));

    shell.pack();
    shell.setSize(400,300);
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Looks like this:

No scrollbar required:

[image]

One scrollbar:

[image]

Comment: Excellent, this works! Unfortunately the columns do not resize if the table gets bigger, but thats no problem! Maybe i will find a solution for that

Comment: @schmusehase [This](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet77.java), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186340/swt-table-auto-resize-all-columns) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211106/swt-table-layout-resize-the-column-of-a-table-to-fill-all-the-available-spac) may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

So I tried mixed code from Baz and me. The result is one scrollbar with resizable columns :)
Thanks a lot !!

```
private static ArrayList<Table> tablesList = new ArrayList<Table>();
private static int groupCount = 3;
private static int colsCount = 3;
private static int itemsCount = 10;
private static boolean firstCheck = true;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    ScrolledComposite scrolledComposite = new ScrolledComposite(shell,
            SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
    scrolledComposite.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(1, false);
    Composite composite = new Composite(scrolledComposite, SWT.NONE);
    composite.setLayout(layout);

    // // MainGroup
    Group gr = new Group(composite, SWT.NONE);
    GridLayout gLayout = new GridLayout(groupCount, false);
    gr.setLayout(gLayout);
    GridData griddata = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false);
    gr.setLayoutData(griddata);
    gr.setText("Main Group");

    for (int i = 0; i < groupCount; i++) {
        createGroups(gr, layout, i);
    }

    scrolledComposite.setContent(composite);
    scrolledComposite.setExpandHorizontal(true);
    scrolledComposite.setExpandVertical(true);
    scrolledComposite.setMinSize(composite.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT,
            SWT.DEFAULT));

    shell.setSize(900, 400);
    shell.open();

    shell.addControlListener(new ControlAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void controlResized(ControlEvent e) {
            resizeColumns();
        }
    });

    if (firstCheck) {
        resizeColumns();
        firstCheck = false;
    }

    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}

private static void resizeColumns() {
    for (Table table : tablesList) {
        TableColumn[] columns = table.getColumns();
        int colCount = columns.length;
        for (TableColumn column : columns) {
            column.setWidth((table.getSize().x - 5) / colCount);
        }
    }
}

private static void createGroups(Composite parentGroup, GridLayout layout,
        int i) {
    Group group = new Group(parentGroup, SWT.NONE);
    group.setLayout(layout);
    GridData griddata1 = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false);
    group.setLayoutData(griddata1);
    group.setText("group " + i);
    createTables(group, i);
}

private static void createTables(Group parent, int tn) {
    Table table = new Table(parent, SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
    tablesList.add(table);
    TableViewer localTableViewer = new TableViewer(table);
    localTableViewer.getControl().setLayoutData(
            new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    for (int j = 0; j < colsCount; j++) {
        TableViewerColumn column = new TableViewerColumn(localTableViewer,
                SWT.NONE);
        column.getColumn().setText("column " + j);
        column.getColumn().pack();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < itemsCount; i++) {
        TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
        item.setText(new String[] { "i ", "am", "table " + tn });
    }
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
}
```